# 301 redirect for certain non-html files

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal-7

I want to do a redirect for certain files that do not end in html, but not all files on my site.  Here is what I have:

This is in Drupal.  For example, for www.mysite.com/test, I want to redirect to www.mysite.com/test.html

Here is what I have.  I'm not sure if it's a Drupal issue, or not.

```
RewriteRule ^test!\.html$ http://www.mysite.com/test.html [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `!\.html` part

```
RewriteRule ^test$ http://www.mysite.com/test.html [R=301,L]
```